# Show partial types depending on a paramter

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
export type ReadPayloadT<T extends keyof ERPTypes> = {
  model: T
  ids: number[]
  fields?: (keyof ERPTypes[T])[]
  with_context?: string
  with_company?: number
}

export const readQuery = async <T extends keyof ERPTypes>(
  payload: ReadPayloadT<T>
): Promise<
  ReadPayloadT<T> extends { fields: (keyof ERPTypes[T])[] }
    ? Pick<ERPTypes[T], keyof ERPTypes[T]>[]
    : ERPTypes[T][]
> => {
  if (!token) {
    let { data } = await auth()
    token = data.access_token
  }
  return axios
    .post(process.env['E_URL'] + '/api/v2/read', payload, {
      headers: {
        DATABASE: process.env['E_DB']!,
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
      },
    })
    .then((res) => res.data)
}

readQuery({
  ids: [234],
  model: 'res.company',
  fields: ['vat'],
}).then((res) => {
  res[0].vat_check_vies
})
```

I have this function "readQuery"

The return type should be `ERPTypes[T]`
If i provide `fields` then the return type should only contain the type of the keys i provided inside `fields`

In this case `res[0]` should only contain `res[0].vat` and nothing else.
If i dont provide `fields` then res[0] should provide every key of `ERPTypes[T]`

So basically, the backend returns me the object with only the propertys of `fields`. If i provide nothing then it returns me the whole object.

I was thinking about overloads, but i want to ask if there is a better idea?

How do i do this?

EDIT:

```
export type ReadPayloadWithFieldsT<T extends keyof ERPTypes> = {
  model: T
  ids: number[]
  fields: (keyof ERPTypes[T])[]
  with_context?: string
  with_company?: number
}
export type ReadPayloadWithoutFieldsT<T extends keyof ERPTypes> = {
  model: T
  ids: number[]
  with_context?: string
  with_company?: number
}

export type ReadQueryOverloadT = {
  <T extends keyof ERPTypes>(payload: ReadPayloadWithFieldsT<T>): Promise<
    Pick<ERPTypes[T], keyof ERPTypes[T]>
  >
  <T extends keyof ERPTypes>(payload: ReadPayloadWithoutFieldsT<T>): Promise<
    ERPTypes[T][]
  >
}

export const readQuery: ReadQueryOverloadT = async (payload) => {
  if (!token) {
    let { data } = await auth()
    token = data.access_token
  }
  return axios
    .post(process.env['E_URL'] + '/api/v2/read', payload, {
      headers: {
        DATABASE: process.env['E_DB']!,
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
      },
    })
    .then((res) => res.data)
}

readQuery({
  ids: [234],
  model: 'res.company',
}).then((res) => {
  res[0]
})
```

I have made it so far.
My problem is now, how do i pick those keys i used in `fields`?

```
 Pick<ERPTypes[T], keyof ERPTypes[T]>
```

With this solution it picks nothing.
In this example it should only pick `vat` because i wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

```
export type ReadPayloadWithFieldsT<
  T extends keyof ERPTypes,
  F extends keyof ERPTypes[T]
> = {
  model: T
  ids: number[]
  fields: F[]
  with_context?: string
  with_company?: number
}
export type ReadPayloadWithoutFieldsT<T extends keyof ERPTypes> = {
  model: T
  ids: number[]
  with_context?: string
  with_company?: number
}

export type ReadQueryOverloadT = {
  <T extends keyof ERPTypes, F extends keyof ERPTypes[T]>(
    payload: ReadPayloadWithFieldsT<T, F>
  ): Promise<Pick<ERPTypes[T], F>[]>
  <T extends keyof ERPTypes>(payload: ReadPayloadWithoutFieldsT<T>): Promise<
    ERPTypes[T][]
  >
}

export const readQuery: ReadQueryOverloadT = async (payload) => {
  if (!token) {
    let { data } = await auth()
    token = data.access_token
  }
  return axios
    .post(process.env['E_URL'] + '/api/v2/read', payload, {
      headers: {
        DATABASE: process.env['E_DB']!,
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
      },
    })
    .then((res) => res.data)
}

readQuery({
  ids: [234],
  model: 'res.company',
  fields: ['vat'],
}).then((res) => {
  res[0].vat //<-- this has only VAT
})
```

I have a solution!